# mobilecore android interstitial not showing

Tags: android, interstitial

I setup the ads on Android as in the resources section but i dont see any ads, i have looked at logcat and it says the interstitial is ready but when testing the `MobileCore.isReady` it returns false.The adunit is set ad Default trigger and i have added the necessary parts into the manifest.

```
public void setupMobileCore() {
        if(payVersion)return;
        MobileCore.setAdUnitEventListener(new AdUnitEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdUnitEvent(MobileCore.AD_UNITS adUnit, EVENT_TYPE eventType,
                                      MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER... trigger) {
                if(adUnit == MobileCore.AD_UNITS.INTERSTITIAL && eventType == AdUnitEventListener.EVENT_TYPE.AD_UNIT_INIT_SUCCEEDED) {
                    MobileCore.loadAdUnit(MobileCore.AD_UNITS.INTERSTITIAL, MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.DEFAULT);
                }
                if(adUnit == MobileCore.AD_UNITS.INTERSTITIAL && eventType == AdUnitEventListener.EVENT_TYPE.AD_UNIT_DISMISSED) {
                             for(MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER myTrigger:trigger){
                                 if(myTrigger.equals(MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.DEFAULT)){
                                     MobileCore.loadAdUnit(MobileCore.AD_UNITS.INTERSTITIAL, MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.DEFAULT);
                                 }
                             }
                }
            }
        });
        MobileCore.init(this, "FEBF7G6ISDBDIFTD7XBJ69PYWBQQ", MobileCore.LOG_TYPE.DEBUG, MobileCore.AD_UNITS.INTERSTITIAL);
    }

    protected static int interstitialsShownNum = 1;

    protected void showInter() {
        if(payVersion)return;
        if (interstitialsShownNum++ % 2 != 0) {//show admob most time
            if (adInter.isLoaded()) {
                adInter.show();
            }
        }
        else {
            if (MobileCore.isReady(MobileCore.AD_UNITS.INTERSTITIAL, MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.DEFAULT)) {
                MobileCore.showInterstitial(this, MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.DEFAULT, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

logs

```
02-25 13:24:05.389: I/MobileCore(13698): mobileCore SDK: Initializing ad_unit_interstitial
02-25 13:24:06.109: I/MobileCore(13698): mobileCore SDK: Initialized successfully ad_unit_interstitial
02-25 13:24:06.109: I/MobileCore(13698): mobileCore SDK: Loading ad_unit_interstitial trigger DEFAULT
02-25 13:24:08.459: I/MobileCore(13698): mobileCore SDK: ad_unit_interstitial trigger DEFAULT is ready
02-25 13:24:19.544: I/MobileCore(13698): MobileCore was already initialized
02-25 13:24:23.079: I/MobileCore(13698): mobileCore SDK: Requesting to show ad_unit_interstitial trigger DEFAULT
02-25 13:24:23.149: I/MobileCore(13698): mobileCore SDK: Failed to show ad_unit_interstitial trigger DEFAULT
```

I think its either a bug or there is no inventory available, i am in Japan. Is there a test mode so can see if its implemented properly without needing local inventory.